# How do I add conditional assets in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Let's call my libraries files `libs.js` with contents:

```
//= require angular
//= require lodash
//= require restangular
//= require angular-mocks if Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: you could rename `libs.js` to `libs.js.erb` and add condition, or use separate files as @Tumas answered

Comment: @Miraage load your file conditionally in layout not in your js file

Answer (score 2):

As @IS04 mentioned and I found results, here is what I need.

Use `libs.js.erb` instead of `libs.js`

```
//= require angular
//= require lodash
//= require restangular
<% require 'angular-mocks' if Rails.env.test? %>
```

Comment: For those stumbling upon this question while looking for a solution for Rails 3 you have to use `require_asset` instead of just `require`

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate files. One for development, the other for production. lib_dev.js and lib.js.

```
# lib.js
//= require angular
//= require lodash 
//= require restangular

# lib_dev.js
//= require ./lib
//= require angular-mocks
```

And then in your layout load the necessary file depending on the environment.

Comment: I'm using this solution right now, but I won't separate.